# How can I stop "Timed out waiting for forcewake old ack to clear"?

Tags: intel, dmesg

Running Arch Linux with Intel i915 and onboard Intel graphics.

If I do a dmesg, I get line after line of "[drm:__gen6_gt_force_wake_mt_get] *ERROR* Timed out waiting for forcewake old ack to clear". Literally there are loads of them!

If I go into TTY2 using Ctrl Alt F2, they continuously appear there too and keep generating every few seconds - the same error.

One fix I came across on the net was to revert commit 36ec8f8774 (drm/i915: unconditionally use mt forcewake on hsw/ivb). I have no idea how to do a "revert commit". Can someone please advise?

Comment: Duplicates http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84649/how-do-i-apply-this-revert-commit-patch-from-git/84651#84651

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest kernel

```
[drm:__gen6_gt_force_wake_mt_get] ERROR Timed out waiting for forcewake old ack to clear
```

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=c11e5f35ab490bd30591563816fbc83526521777

No need to revert the commit, just [update your kernel.](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/06/compile-linux-kernel/)

You can see this for yourself by downloading the kernel, and looking at /drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_pm.c lines 240 - 260 and comparing them to the patch mentioned on this link.
  https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=c11e5f35ab490bd30591563816fbc83526521777

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1080360

Comment: Thanks. I'm on Arch Linux and my current updated kernal from Arch's own repos is 3.10.3-1. I assume this is the updated one as above and includes this patch? However, in /lib/modules/3.0.87-1-lts/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm, I only see i915.ko.gz and no intel_pm.c. So will this fix still work for me? If I do a dmesg now, I see loads of "[drm:__gen6_gt_force_wake_mt_get] ERROR Timed out waiting for forcewake old ack to clear" lines.

Comment: This problem has just been fixed for me now after updating today.

Comment: @nLinked glad to hear!