# How do I apply this revert commit patch from git?

Tags: drivers, git, patch

I have found a patch applicable to my system to fix a problem but I have no idea how to get this patch and then apply it. Can anybody help me please?

Patch: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=c11e5f35ab490bd30591563816fbc83526521777

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, download the patch. There is a handy patch button on the link you indicated. Say for instance, you saved it to /tmp/foo.patch

cd into the source directory and run the following

```
cd drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_pm.c  
patch -p1 < /tmp/foo.patch
```

You could alternatively use git-am to create and apply the patch. Assuming you have checked out the linux kernel.   https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-am.html

**Resources**

[Applying Patches](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/applying-patches.txt)
[Building Kernel](http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelBuild)

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if I am going into the right directory (/lib/modules/3.0.87-1-lts/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm), because I only see i915.ko.gz in there, and no intel_pm.c. Yet I still get the problem as here (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81218/how-can-i-stop-timed-out-waiting-for-forcewake-old-ack-to-clear). I'm not sure why I don't have intel_pm.c in there so unfortunately can't apply the patch :(

Comment: You will apply the patch to the kernel, then recompile and install. (I've added a link to my answer showing how to compile your kernel). I've checked the latest stable kernel listed on kernel.org, and it appears that the patch is already applied. `git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git`          `git log |grep c11e5f35ab490bd30591563816fbc83526521777 `. You just need to update your kernel, and you should have this patch automatically included.

Comment: Thanks for checking for me. Great to hear it is fixed in the latest kernal. I am just checking your reply to my other bug linked in my comment above.